# Getting syntax error when declaring FOREIGN KEYS in MYSQL (using innoDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
>
> `book_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> `book_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> `courseid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> **FOREIGN KEY ('courseid') REFERENCES 'course'('course_id') ON DELETE CASCADE**
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
>
> `course_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> `year` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> `section` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

I want to make courseid(under books table) a foreign key referencing course_id (under course table) but getting the following error message:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''courseid')
    REFERENCES 'course'('course_id')

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARS' at line 15**

I tired several syntax for declaring Foreign key (using CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY, with/without quotes etc) but none worked.

I am using Xamp WITH Server version: 5.5.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL).

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Edit:  Syntax error is fixed but now I am getting this error:  "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (testlib2.books, CONSTRAINT books_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (courseid) REFERENCES course (course_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)"

Comment: NVM .. fixed it.  had to add values for each referencing keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use back-ticks ` instead of single quotes also first create course table then create books table so that books table can able to point course table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course (
  course_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  YEAR VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  section VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (course_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
  book_id VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  book_title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  courseid VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`courseid`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 ;
```

[**See fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2471b)

Comment: I think my syntax problem is fixed but now I am getting the following error:  "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testlib2`.`books`, CONSTRAINT `books_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`courseid`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)"

Answer (score 1):

make it simply as :

**your code:**

```
FOREIGN KEY ('courseid') REFERENCES 'course'('course_id') ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**change:**

```
FOREIGN KEY (`courseid`) REFERENCES `course` (`course_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And you must going to create the **primary key table of course(course_id)** and then after only should to be create the reference **foreign key table of books(courseid)**.

Comment: Why are the `\`` chars necessary?